# SQL QUERY: IF Customer is NEW then 1 else 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to find the query that allows me to find when a new customer has an invoice then mark that client as 1 for 'NEW' and then group it by by EOMONTH(date)

The columns I have in the database

```
Date     
Account_Id   
Account_Name    
Revenue
```

Final output would look something like this

```
Date            Account Id    Account Name    Revenue  Status
30/06/2023      123           123 Limited     £123     1
30/06/2023      1234          1234 Limited    £1000    0
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: how do you know if a customer has an invoice?

Comment: never save currency in columns

Comment: Please show sample data **and** desired results.

Comment: @nbk i dont save currency in tables - it was just an example. But thank you for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considered that invoices has separate table follow below query

```
select eOmonth(date) Date, Account_Id, Account_Name, sum(Revenue) Revenue
    , (case when (select top 1 1 from Invoices where Invoices.DocumentNumber = customer.Account_Id) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) status
from customer
group by eOmonth(date), Account_Id, Account_Name
```

If invoice is with in the table follow below query

```
select eOmonth(date) Date, Account_Id, Account_Name, sum(Revenue) Revenue
    , (case when Invoice is not null then 1 else 0 end) status
from customer
group by eOmonth(date), Account_Id, Account_Name
    , (case when Invoice is not null then 1 else 0 end)
```

Use `CASE` expression based on your requirements.

Comment: comment need any changes.